# Join from sql table to Excel Sheet

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, vba

Facing run-time error says

> Incorrect Syntex

Near `C:\Users\Emp_ID\Desktop\FolderName\FileName.xlsm`

```
set rs = cnn.Execute("update EO_datawh.dbo.TableName set email_status = 'Sent' From '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'.'Sheet1$' a join EO_datawh.dbo.TableName b on a.sr_number = b.sr_number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias 'b' instead of 'EO_datawh.dbo.TableName' after the UPDATE:

```
set rs = cnn.Execute("update b set email_status = 'Sent' From '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'.'Sheet1$' a join EO_datawh.dbo.TableName b on a.sr_number = b.sr_number")
```

Comment: Same error Syas Incorrect Syntax Near 'C:\Users\Emp_ID\Desktop\FolderName\FileName.xlsm'